# how to import polymer correctly when hosting on parse

Tags: html, node.js, express, parse-platform, polymer

I'm having trouble getting polymer elements to show up on my parse app.

The file directory looks like this:

```
/cloud
    /views
    app.js
    main.js

/config
    global.json

/public 
    /components
    /css
    index.html
```

in index.html I have the imports like this:

```
<!-- css -->
<link type='text/css' rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">

<!-- polymer -->
<link rel="import" href="../components/paper-tabs/paper-tabs.html">
```

and a paper button in the body:

```
<paper-button>PAPER BUTTON</paper-button>
```

However, when I deploy, the paper button doesn't show up. The css is applied correctly though, which is so weird, since if /public/index.html can access /css then why not /components??

To debug I moved the `step-1` folder from the polymer tutorial into /public so that the file directory is like this:

```
/cloud
    /views
    app.js
    main.js

/config
    global.json

/public 
    /components
    /css
    /step-1
        index.html
    index.html
```

I've verified that when I run the app on localhost and go to

```
http://localhost:8000/public/step-1/
```

The polymer elements show up correctly. I'm unable to access this on the deployed parse app though, and I'm not sure how to set up routing correctly.

btw, app.js contains the default routing configurations:

```
app.set('views', 'cloud/views');  // Specify the folder to find templates
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');    // Set the template engine
app.use(express.bodyParser());    // Middleware for reading request body
```

I looked at the expressjs docs and tried adding

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/bower_components'));
```

and installing polymer at the app's root directory and using corresponding imports, but it still doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOL. Forgot the polymer js import and imported paper tabs instead of paper button.

Fixed:

```
<!-- polymer -->
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue, The samples what polymer has given they run correctly on python http server.